# SonarQube TFS Extension auto updates

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, task, auto-update, auto

We have an on-premises TFS instance in our company, and we notice that the sonarqube extension is getting updated automatically. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts

We are worried to have it updated automatically in our production environments, is it really the way it was designed to work? Is there a way to do the updates manually instead or a continuous delivery model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an expected behavior. In TFS 2017 we added a feature to automatically check for updated external extensions once a day and upgrade them. No way to stop this unless you use a prior version of TFS.

Answer (score -1):

If the account running the TFS Services does not have access to the internet then the jobs will just be marked as failed. They will still attempt to update everyday. To update, you then just have to download the VSIX from the Marketplace and upload it to your local gallery to update the extensions